# GZIP compression to a byte array

Tags: java, android, stream, gzip

I am trying to write a class that can compress data. The below code fails (no exception is thrown, but the target .gz file is empty.)
Besides: I don't want to generate the .gz file directly like it is done in all examples. I only want to get the compressed
data, so that I can e.g. encrypt it before writting the data to a file.

If I write directly to a file everything works fine:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class Zipper
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {    
    byte[] dataToCompress = "This is the test data."
      .getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

    GZIPOutputStream zipStream = null;
    FileOutputStream fileStream = null;
    try
    {
      fileStream = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/zip_file.gz");
      zipStream = new GZIPOutputStream(fileStream);
      zipStream.write(dataToCompress);

      fileStream.write(compressedData);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      try{ zipStream.close(); }
        catch(Exception e){ }
      try{ fileStream.close(); }
        catch(Exception e){ }
    }
  }
}
```

But, if I want to 'bypass' it to the byte array stream it does not produce a single byte - `compressedData` is always empty.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class Zipper
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {    
    byte[] dataToCompress = "This is the test data."
      .getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    byte[] compressedData = null;

    GZIPOutputStream zipStream = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = null;
    FileOutputStream fileStream = null;
    try
    {
      byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(dataToCompress.length);
      zipStream = new GZIPOutputStream(byteStream);
      zipStream.write(dataToCompress);

      compressedData = byteStream.toByteArray();

      fileStream = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/zip_file.gz");
      fileStream.write(compressedData);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      try{ zipStream.close(); }
        catch(Exception e){ }
      try{ byteStream.close(); }
        catch(Exception e){ }
      try{ fileStream.close(); }
        catch(Exception e){ }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "*The below code fails*" is not a valid Java error message.

Comment: Please also include the stack trace from the error.

Comment: It just generates a file that is not a ZIP archive. There is no error message.

Comment: duh. there is no error message because you do'nt log anything in your exceptions.

Comment: It's generally true in programming that if you can't clearly describe what it is you want to do, you can't do it.

Comment: It does not produce any exception that could be logged.
The 'assembling' of the ZIP file must be done wrong.

Comment: So, you're trying to generate a ZIP archive, but also **not** generate a ZIP archive

Comment: Your code produces a perfectly fine ZIP archive for me btw.

Comment: Also, to get just a stream of compressed data, use `DeflaterOutputStream` or `GZipOutputStream`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem is that you are not closing the `GZIPOutputStream`.  Until you close it the output will be incomplete.

You just need to close it *before* reading the byte array.  You need to reorder the `finally` blocks to achieve this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class Zipper
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {    
    byte[] dataToCompress = "This is the test data."
      .getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

    try
    {
      ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream =
        new ByteArrayOutputStream(dataToCompress.length);
      try
      {
        GZIPOutputStream zipStream =
          new GZIPOutputStream(byteStream);
        try
        {
          zipStream.write(dataToCompress);
        }
        finally
        {
          zipStream.close();
        }
      }
      finally
      {
        byteStream.close();
      }

      byte[] compressedData = byteStream.toByteArray();

      FileOutputStream fileStream =
        new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/zip_file.gz");
      try
      {
        fileStream.write(compressedData);
      }
      finally
      {
        try{ fileStream.close(); }
          catch(Exception e){ /* We should probably delete the file now? */ }
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I do not recommend inititalizing the stream variables to `null`, because it means your `finally` block can also throw a `NullPointerException`.

Also note that you can declare `main` to throw `IOException` (then you would not need the outermost `try` statement.)

There is little point in swallowing exceptions from `zipStream.close();`, because if it throws an exception you will not have a valid .gz file (so you should not proceed to write it.)

Also I would not swallow exceptions from `byteStream.close();` but for a different reason - they should never be thrown (i.e. there is a bug in your JRE and you would want to know about that.)

Comment: you need to close GZIPOutputStream or else will get partial data

Answer (score 33):

I've improved JITHINRAJ's code - used [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
private static byte[] gzipCompress(byte[] uncompressedData) {
        byte[] result = new byte[]{};
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(uncompressedData.length);
             GZIPOutputStream gzipOS = new GZIPOutputStream(bos)) {
            gzipOS.write(uncompressedData);
            // You need to close it before using bos
            gzipOS.close();
            result = bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

private static byte[] gzipUncompress(byte[] compressedData) {
        byte[] result = new byte[]{};
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressedData);
             ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             GZIPInputStream gzipIS = new GZIPInputStream(bis)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = gzipIS.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            result = bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: `gzipOS.close();` is not necessary here since `GZIPOutputStream` is `AutoCloseable`.

Comment: `gzipOS.close();` is still required! Without it, Gzip compression will be invalid. Please try and fix

Comment: @YanislavKornev you're absolutely right! If I don't close `gzipOS` I'll get incorrect array

Comment: How do I know how long the compressed array is? `toByteArray` compresses my array, but does not remove the trailing zeros.

Comment: @cansik you can use result.length. You can get more information about gzip alg-m here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip

Comment: @slartidan what happens if an exception arises?

Comment: True... Forget what I said :)

Comment: You don't need to use gzipOS.close(); You only need gzipOS.finish();, and let java close it for you.

Answer (score 6):

If you are still looking an answer you can use the below code to get the compressed byte[] using deflater and decompress it using inflater.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Some string for testing
        String sr = new String("fsdfesfsfdddddddsfdsfssdfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsdfggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggghghghghggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggfsdfesfsfdddddddsfdsfssdfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsdfggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggghghghghggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg");
        byte[] data = sr.getBytes();
        System.out.println("src size "+data.length);
        try {
            compress(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static byte[] compress(byte[] data) throws IOException { 
        Deflater deflater = new Deflater(); 
        deflater.setInput(data); 
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);  

        deflater.finish(); 
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
        while (!deflater.finished()) { 
        int count = deflater.deflate(buffer);  
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);  
        } 
        outputStream.close(); 
        byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray(); 

        System.out.println("Original: " + data.length  ); 
        System.out.println("Compressed: " + output.length ); 
        return output; 
        }
```

Comment: This is an invalid answer, as Inflater and Deflater use Zlib instead of GZip.

Answer (score 2):

**To compress**

```
private static byte[] compress(byte[] uncompressedData) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
        GZIPOutputStream gzipOS = null;
        try {
            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(uncompressedData.length);
            gzipOS = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
            gzipOS.write(uncompressedData);
            gzipOS.close();
            return bos.toByteArray();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                assert gzipOS != null;
                gzipOS.close();
                bos.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }
        return new byte[]{};
    }
```

**To uncompress**

```
private byte[] uncompress(byte[] compressedData) {
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
        GZIPInputStream gzipIS = null;

        try {
            bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressedData);
            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            gzipIS = new GZIPInputStream(bis);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while((len = gzipIS.read(buffer)) != -1){
                bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            return bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                assert gzipIS != null;
                gzipIS.close();
                bos.close();
                bis.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return new byte[]{};
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the examples have wrong exception handling.

```java
public static byte[] gzipBytes(byte[] payload) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(baos)) {
        gzip.write(payload);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
    // note: toByteArray should be called after try-with-resources, not inside
    return baos.toByteArray();
}

public static byte[] gunzipBytes(byte[] gzPayload) {
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(gzPayload);
    try (GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(bais)) {
        // java 9+ required for this method
        return gzip.readAllBytes();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException("Error while unpacking gzip content", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below function, it is tested and working fine.

In general, your code has serious problem of *ignoring* the exceptions! returning `null` or simply not printing anything in the `catch` block will make it very difficult to debug

You do not have to write the zip output to a file if you want to process it further (e.g. encrypt it), you can easily modify the code to write the output to in-memory stream

```
public static String zip(File inFile, File zipFile) throws IOException {        
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inFile);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
    ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

    try {
        zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(inFile.getName()));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int len;
        while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            zout.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        zout.closeEntry();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        try{zout.close();}catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
        try{fis.close();}catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}         
    }
    return zipFile.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Comment: It is possible to add each of these `close()` statement in a `try/catch` block and ignore the error

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code..

```
try {
    String inputFileName = "test.txt";  //may use your file_Path
    String zipFileName = "compressed.zip";

    //Create input and output streams
    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(inputFileName);
    ZipOutputStream outStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName));

    // Add a zip entry to the output stream
    outStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(inputFileName));

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;

    //Each chunk of data read from the input stream
    //is written to the output stream
    while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    //Close zip entry and file streams
    outStream.closeEntry();

    outStream.close();
    inStream.close();

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also may be helpful this one..

- http://www.java-samples.com/java/zip_files_in_a_folder_using_java.htm

Comment: This code writes directly to a ZIP file; which is what I don't want. But thank you anyway.