# How to zip- compress HTTP request with Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, http, http-compression

How to gzip HTTP **request**, created by `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate?`

I am using `Spring 4.2.6` with Spring `Boot 1.3.5` (Java SE, not Android or Javascript in the web browser).

I am making some really big `POST` requests, and I want **request body** to be compressed.

Comment: You can give a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410317/using-gzip-compression-with-spring-boot-mvc-javaconfig-with-restful
there are instructions on how to turn on compression in Boot and non Boot and some performance advices.

Comment: @Maxvader , linked answer is for response compression. I want request compression.

Comment: [Compressing HTTP Post Data sent from browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031968/compressing-http-post-data-sent-from-browser) is about compressing request that orginates from Javascript. My request originates from Java.

Comment: Does you look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#how-to-enable-http-response-compression ?

Comment: iMysak, liked documentation is about **server response** compression. I would like to compress **request body**.

Comment: Any updates on this one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I propose two solutions, one simpler without streaming and one that supports streaming.

If you **don't require streaming**, use a custom [`ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.html), a Spring feature.

```
RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
rt.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(interceptor));
```

Where `interceptor` could be:

```
ClientHttpRequestInterceptor interceptor = new ClientHttpRequestInterceptor() {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
            throws IOException {
        request.getHeaders().add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        byte[] gzipped = getGzip(body);
        return execution.execute(request, gzipped);
    } 
 }
```

`getGzip` I [copied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14783672/1536382)

```
    private byte[] getGzip(byte[] body) throws IOException {

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            GZIPOutputStream zipStream = new GZIPOutputStream(byteStream);
            try {
                zipStream.write(body);
            } finally {
                zipStream.close();
            }
        } finally {
            byteStream.close();
        }

        byte[] compressedData = byteStream.toByteArray();
        return compressedData;

    }
```

After configuring the interceptor all requests will be zipped.

The disadvantage of this approach is that it does not support streaming as the `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` receives the content as a `byte[]`

If you **require streaming** create a custom `ClientHttpRequestFactory`, say `GZipClientHttpRequestFactory`, and use it like this:

```
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
    ClientHttpRequestFactory gzipRequestFactory = new GZipClientHttpRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate(gzipRequestFactory);
```

Where `GZipClientHttpRequestFactory` is:

```
public class GZipClientHttpRequestFactory extends AbstractClientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper {

    public GZipClientHttpRequestFactory(ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory) {
        super(requestFactory);
    }

    @Override
    protected ClientHttpRequest createRequest(URI uri, HttpMethod httpMethod, ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory)
            throws IOException {
        ClientHttpRequest delegate = requestFactory.createRequest(uri, httpMethod);
        return new ZippedClientHttpRequest(delegate);
    }

}
```

And `ZippedClientHttpRequest` is:

```
public class ZippedClientHttpRequest extends WrapperClientHttpRequest
{
    private GZIPOutputStream zip;

    public ZippedClientHttpRequest(ClientHttpRequest delegate) {
        super(delegate);
        delegate.getHeaders().add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        // here or in getBody could add content-length to avoid chunking
        // but is it available ? 
        // delegate.getHeaders().add("Content-Length", "39");

    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getBody() throws IOException {
        final OutputStream body = super.getBody();
        zip = new GZIPOutputStream(body);
        return zip;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse execute() throws IOException {
        if (zip!=null) zip.close();
        return super.execute();
    }

}
```

And finally `WrapperClientHttpRequest` is:

```
public class WrapperClientHttpRequest implements ClientHttpRequest {

    private final ClientHttpRequest delegate;

    protected WrapperClientHttpRequest(ClientHttpRequest delegate) {
        super();
        if (delegate==null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null delegate");
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    protected final ClientHttpRequest getDelegate() {
        return delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getBody() throws IOException {
        return delegate.getBody();
    }

    @Override
    public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
        return delegate.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    public URI getURI() {
        return delegate.getURI();
    }

    @Override
    public HttpMethod getMethod() {
        return delegate.getMethod();
    }

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse execute() throws IOException {
        return delegate.execute();
    }
}
```

This approach creates a request with [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), this can be changed setting the content length header, if size is known.

The advantage of the `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` and/or custom `ClientHttpRequestFactory` approach is that it works with any method of RestTemplate. An alternate approach, passing a [RequestCallback](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RequestCallback.html) is possible only with [`execute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#execute-java.net.URI-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.web.client.RequestCallback-org.springframework.web.client.ResponseExtractor-) methods, this because the other methods of RestTemplate internally create their own RequestCallback(s) that produce the content.

BTW it seems that there is [little support to decompress gzip request on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507007/http-request-compression). Also related: [Sending gzipped data in WebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183691/sending-gzipped-data-in-webrequest/1184122#1184122) that points to the [Zip Bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb) issue. I think you will have to write [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29096025/1536382) for it.

Comment: This interceptor gets full request body and then compresses it in a one step. Am I correct? This is not suitable for sending really big POST requests, as OP requested.

Comment: @berserkk Yes, correct, it does not support streaming, I updated the answer. Let's see if is enough or not. The advantage of this is that works with any method of RestTemplate. Passing a RequestCallback is possible only with `execute` methods, for the others is RestTemplate that internally creates its own RequestCallback.  btw i am not the downvoter ;-)

Comment: Your explanation is enough for me. Please, update your answer once again, so I can upvote it later. Thanks.

Comment: I've added an answer to supplement the one above from @TestoTestini to take advantage of Java 7+'s 'try-with-resources' syntax for the `getGzip` method since both OutputStreams are `Closeable`. I couldn't make it look readable in this comment block, hence submitted it as an additional 'Answer' below.

Answer (score 2):

Further to the above answer from @TestoTestini, if we take advantage of Java 7+'s 'try-with-resources' syntax (since both `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `GZIPOutputStream` implement closeable() ) then we can shrink the getGzip function into the following:

```
private byte[] getGzip(byte[] body) throws IOException {

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         GZIPOutputStream zipStream = new GZIPOutputStream(byteStream)) {
            zipStream.write(body);
        byte[] compressedData = byteStream.toByteArray();
        return compressedData;
    }

}
```

(I couldn't find a way of commenting on @TestoTestini's original answer and retaining the above code format, hence this Answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment on @roj 's post I'm writing an answer here.

@roj snippet although is neat it actually does not do the same job as @Testo Testini 's snippet.

Testo is closing the streams before:
`byteStream.toByteArray();`
where in @rog answer, this occurs before the `stream.close()`, since streams are in the try/resource block.

If you need to use try-with-resources, `zipStream` should be closed before the `byteStream.toByteArray();`

The complete snippet should be:

```
private byte[] getGzip(byte[] body) throws IOException {

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         GZIPOutputStream zipStream = new GZIPOutputStream(byteStream)) {
            
        zipStream.write(body);
        zipStream.close();

        byte[] compressedData = byteStream.toByteArray();
        return compressedData;
    }

}
```

The was getting an error ("Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached") and the above fixed the error in my case and I thought that I should share this.