# How to compress the body of Spring WebClient post request?

Tags: spring-boot, reactor-netty, spring-webclient

I am doing some testing with Spring WebClient. In the following codes, I have set the compress to true. However when I check the debug logs, I can see the "accept-encoding: gzip" header is added, but the body is not compressed. Any way to force compress on post request body? Thanks.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().compress(true).wiretap(true);

WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .build();

Post post = new Post();

        post.setUserId(1000L);
        post.setId(2000L);
        post.setTitle("Reactor Netty");

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        IntStream.range(1, 1000).forEach(i -> sb.append("Spring boot webclient"));
        post.setBody(sb.toString());

        Post p = webClient.post().uri("/posts").syncBody(post).retrieve().bodyToMono(Post.class).block();
```

Comment: Do you want to send the post request body compressed or you want to receive the response compressed?

Comment: Both way. The compress() method gives me the impression that this task is taken care of by the library.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031968/compressing-http-post-data-sent-from-browser).

`.compress(true)` is for the server to response as gzip. That's why your post body is not compressed.

I am not familiar with manual http-client and web-client. When I use Spring, I use RestTemplate. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415294/how-to-zip-compress-http-request-with-spring-resttemplate/44467789) details how to force zipping your request body.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One can definitely gzip the body with extra codes. But I was thinking this common task may be available out of box.

Comment: `compress(true)` is for the server responses. For the request body, Netty does not support it by default: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/2132

Comment: @VioletaGeorgieva Thanks Violeta! You answered my question.