# Convert GZIPOutputStream to byte array

Tags: java, arrays, gzipoutputstream

I already have a GZIPOutput stream which has already defined. Now I want to convert it to a  byte array.

I tried the code below. But it gives an error.

```
GZIPOutputStream zipStream = createGZIP();
byte[] compressedData = zipStream.toByteArray();
```

error : cannot resolve method "toByteArray()"

checked [GZIP compression to a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777800/gzip-compression-to-a-byte-array) , but it is inputting a byte[]. I need to convert a gzip which I already have.

Comment: What is the error and where is was it thrown?

Comment: What exception or error is it giving? Please post that here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GZIP compression to a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777800/gzip-compression-to-a-byte-array)

Comment: @Ashish updated with the error

Comment: Can you post the createGZIP() method please?

Comment: Hey @AnjuT - didn't get you (missing link probably in your answer?). Can you please post the createGZIP() method here so we can suggest what could be done to get the byte array. Thank you.

Comment: to compress the zip file I refered this. https://www.journaldev.com/966/java-gzip-example-compress-decompress-file

Comment: Why do you think that `GZipOutputStream has a `toByteArray()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a GZIPOutput stream which has already defined. Now I want to convert it to a byte array.

You will need to modify the method that is creating the `GZIPOutputStream` so that it sends it to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Alternatively, after closing the `FileOutputStream` for the file where you are (presumably) writing the compressed data, open it for input and read it into a byte array.

---

Concerning your current attempt:

```
GZIPOutputStream zipStream = createGZIP();
byte[] compressedData = zipStream.toByteArray();
```

This approach is not going to work.

- `GZIPOutputStream` provides no API methods for retrieving the compressed data.
- `GZIPOutputStream` provides no API methods for retrieving the stream that `GZIPOutputStream` is writing to.  (And even if there was, most `OutputStream` types don't allow you to retrieve the data ...)

In general, it is better to find and read the javadocs for the classes that you use.  Programming by *guessing* what methods they provide is liable to lead you to waste your time when your guess are wrong.